# Javascript reg exp not right

Tags: javascript, regex

Here is a string `str = '.js("aaa").js("bbb").js("ccc")'`, I want to write a regular expression to return an Array like this:

```
[aaa, bbb, ccc];
```

My regular expression is:

```
var jsReg = /.js\(['"](.*)['"]\)/g;
var jsAssets = [];
var js;
while ((js = jsReg.exec(find)) !== null) {
    jsAssets.push(js[1]);
}
```

But the jsAssets result is

```
[""aaa").js("bbb").js("ccc""]
```

What's wrong with this regular expression?

Answer (score 2):

Use the lazy version of `.*`:

```
/\.js\(['"](.*?)['"]\)/g
              ^
```

And it would be better if you escape the first dot.

This will match the least number of characters until the next quote.

[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8HSYZ/1/)

If you want to allow escaped quotes, use something like this:

```
/\.js\(['"]((?:\\['"]|[^"])+)['"]\)/g
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/yY5kK1)

Answer (score 1):

I believe it can be done in one-liner with `replace and match` method calls:

```
var str = '.js("aaa").js("bbb").js("ccc")';

str.replace(/[^(]*\("([^"]*)"\)[^(]*/g, '$1,').match(/[^,]+/g);
//=> ["aaa", "bbb", "ccc"]
```

Answer (score 0):

In

```
/.js\(['"](.*)['"]\)/g
```

matches as much as possible, and does not capture group 1, so it matches

```
"aaa").js("bbb").js("ccc"
```

but given your example input.

Try

```
/\.js\(('(?:[^\\']|\\.)*'|"(?:[\\"]|\\.)*"))\)/
```

To break this down,

1. `\.` matches a literal dot
2. `\.js\(` matches the literal string ".js("
3. `(` starts to capture the string.
4. `[^\\']|\\.` matches a character other than quote or backslash or an escaped non-line terminator.
5. `(?:[\\']|\\.)*` matches the body of a string
6. `'(?:[\\']|\\.)*'` matches a single quoted string
7. `(...|...)` captures a single quoted or double quoted string
8. `)\)` closes the capturing group and matches a literal close parenthesis

---

The second major problem is your loop.

You're doing a global match repeatedly which makes no sense.

Get rid of the `g` modifier, and then things should work better.

Comment: `[^\\']` will not allow escaped quotes.

Comment: @Jerry, that's why it's followed by `|\\.`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using `.*`. That will match any character. You'll have to be a bit more specific with what you are trying to capture.

If it will only ever be word characters you could use `\w` which matches any word character. This includes `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`: uppercase, lowercase, numbers and an underscore.

So your regex would look something like this :

```
var jsReg = /js\(['"](\w*)['"]\)/g;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one - http://jsfiddle.net/UDYAq/

```
var str = new String('.js("aaa").js("bbb").js("ccc")');

var regex = /\.js\(\"(.*?)\"\){1,}/gi;
var result = [];

result = str.match (regex);

for (i in result) {
    result[i] = result[i].match(/\"(.*?)\"/i)[1];
}

console.log (result);
```

Answer (score 0):

To be sure that matched characters are surrounded by the same quotes:

```
/\.js\((['"])(.*?)\1\)/g
```